# How can I upgrade to Windows 10 and still dual boot?

Tags: 14.04, dual-boot, upgrade, windows-8, windows-10

I currently have Windows 8.1 and Ubuntu 14.04.

I want to upgrade windows from 8 to 10. But I am afraid that it will break the Ubuntu dual-boot configuration.

Please guide me how to upgrade to Windows 10 without breaking Ubuntu dual boot.

Comment: UEFI or BIOS installs? BIOS may have issues as Windows rewrites partition table without Linux partition if logical. Best to then backup partition table. Those with UEFI seem to work, but you do need good backups of both Windows & Ubuntu. Even some Windows upgrades fail halfway thru and then system must be restored. And have Ubuntu live installer to use as repair tool to reset Ubuntu as first in UEFI.

Comment: Why are we suppose to know what an W10 upgrade does to your system? Plus... you do know you can re-install grub using the live dvd? So basically it should not matter...

Answer (score 0):

Today I upgraded the windows 8.1 to Windows 10. I was able to upgrade it without any issues with Ubuntu dual boot. No extra steps needed to secure or restore the dual boot ubuntu. It just worked itself. Note that I had UEFI.